# Flutter: Error "The 'Pods-Runner' target has frameworks with conflicting names" after upgraded flutter version

Tags: flutter, cocoapods, flutter-dependencies, podfile, flutter-ffmpeg

I cannot run my code on my own iPhone, after I upgraded my flutter project from 2.23 to 2.8 and updated all the packages, this is a project that I worked on a few months ago, and now there is a new version of flutter, so I thought it would be better to keep my SDK and the packages up to date, but I got an error saying `Exception: Error running pod install` when I'm trying to test it on my phone :(

**Here is the error:**

```
[!] The 'Pods-Runner' target has frameworks with conflicting names: libavcodec.framework, libavdevice.framework, libavfilter.framework, libavformat.framework, libavutil.framework, libswresample.framework, libswscale.framework, gmp.framework, gnutls.framework, libhogweed.framework, libnettle.framework, mobileffmpeg.framework, lame.framework, libilbc.framework, libogg.framework, libopencore-amrnb.framework, libsndfile.framework, libvorbis.framework, libvorbisenc.framework, libvorbisfile.framework, opus.framework, shine.framework, soxr.framework, speex.framework, twolame.framework, vo-amrwbenc.framework, and wavpack.framework.
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:67:in `verify_no_duplicate_names'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in verify_no_duplicate_framework_and_library_names'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:48:in `each_key'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:48:in `block in verify_no_duplicate_framework_and_library_names'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:47:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:47:in `verify_no_duplicate_framework_and_library_names'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:37:in `validate!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:597:in `validate_targets'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:163:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

Exception: Error running pod install
```

I had also tried some popular solutions on the web such as running the command:

```
pod install --repo-update
```

But I got the same error.

My podfile:
[image: Podfile screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your `pod` file contains `old data` as well so for this I'll suggest you to **deintegrate** pod first then `reinstall` it

```
pod deintegrate // run this command to deintegrate
```

then isntall the pod again

```
pod install
```

also perform `flutter clean` before after this process

If the above solutions doesn't work you may try these steps as well

first of all just drag and drop your **IOS** folder into the `terminal`

then clear the cache of the pod file using below command

```
pod cache clean --all
```

after the above steps just run `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` command

and finally you just run the below `command`

```
pod install
```

Let me know whether it works for you or not.

Comment: Thx though, but the error is still standing strong~

Comment: Please check the updated answer.

Comment: The error is still there when running `pod install`.

Comment: Oh, and also the command `pod cache clean -all` needs 2 dashes~

Comment: okay last thing from my side that you can try is go through the this article and try deleting derived data of your Xcode https://www.raywenderlich.com/19998365-understanding-and-managing-xcode-space

Answer (score 1):

When I run into build issues like this I do 3 things. First make sure you stop any running instance of the program, then do these 3 things.

1. Delete the (ios | android | web | macos | etc) folder entirely. Whichever one is giving you troubles, delete that folder
2. From root of project folder run "flutter clean"
3. From root of project folder run "flutter create ."

Comment: Thx for the answer, but I'm still getting that error~

Answer (score 0):

Your `Podfile` may have an old format.

you can try formatting as like this example https://github.com/tanersener/flutter-ffmpeg/blob/master/example/ios/Podfile

Or

Try running `pod install` command in the ios folder.

Or

Try `flutter clean`

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried to format my file just like the example above but it doesn't work, and by running `pod install`, I got an error like this `[!] The 'Pods-Runner' target has frameworks with conflicting names: libavcodec.framework, libavdevice.framework, libavfilter.framework, libavformat.framework, libavutil.framework, libswresample.framework, and libswscale.framework.`

Comment: can you share Podfile?

Comment: Just edited, by setting the `global platform version` to 9.3 made the log much shorter though, but still cannot run on my iPhone.

Comment: it must work if you have edited as per example...try flutter clean.

Comment: I actually copied the whole podfile doc from the example, but the problem still exists, so I thought if it could be the problem of the flutter framework itself~

Comment: when you upgrade the version such an error may arrises, so you can watch whats happening in the project using flutter doctor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240141/discussion-between-ryan-wang-and-gretal).

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading my cocoapods back to 1.11.3 work... Just a temporary fix

Answer (score 0):

This will happen, once you copy the project from another project because project compatible structure not creating. so you must recreate platform folders/directories that are compatible with the Flutter project.

1. "flutter clean"
2. "flutter create ."
3. "flutter run"

In the second point, don't miss the DOT with CREATE command.